# Figuring out odd even and zeros

Tags: java

I am having problems with my java program. I have to input a value then print out the number of odds, evens, and zeroes. The odds and zeroes display fine but the evens display total digits.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class OddEvenZero 
{
public static void main(String[] args)
{
int even = 0;
int odd = 0;
int zero = 0;
int placeInValue;

Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

System.out.println("Enter a Value: ");
String valueEntered = scan.nextLine();

for(placeInValue = 0; placeInValue < valueEntered.length(); placeInValue ++)
{
    char value = valueEntered.charAt(placeInValue);

    int numberUsedInLoop = Integer.parseInt(Character.toString(value));

    if(numberUsedInLoop == 0)
    {
        zero ++;
    }
    else if(numberUsedInLoop%2 == 0);
    {
        even ++;
    }
    if(numberUsedInLoop%2 != 0 && numberUsedInLoop != 0)
    {
        odd ++;
    }

}
System.out.println("Number of Zeroes in Number: " + zero);
System.out.println("Number of Evens in Number: " + even);
System.out.println("Number of Odds in Number: " + odd);
}
}
```

Output:
Enter a Value: 
225500
Number of Zeroes in Number: 2
Number of Evens in Number: 6
Number of Odds in Number: 2
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: There is a semi-colon at the end of that if statement `if(numberUsedInLoop%2 == 0);` remove it

Comment: `;` after an `if` condition makes the `if` with no body. Then `{ even ++; }` executes unconditionally.

Comment: Thank you so much. I can't believe I didn't see that.

Answer (score 2):

The semicolon terminates the `else if` immediately here

```
else if(numberUsedInLoop%2 == 0); // <-- terminates the else if
{ // <-- raw block
    even ++;
}
```

change it to something like

```
else if(numberUsedInLoop%2 == 0)
{
    even ++;
}
else // <-- just an else should satisfy your conditions
{
    odd ++;
}
```